# Date(D) function in PHP Does not work without quotes on xampp

Tags: php, syntax

`Date(D)` function in PHP Does not work without quotes on xampp

In this following code

```
$D = date(D);
if ($D == Mon) {
    week = 1;
    $weeks .= "(FIND_IN_SET($week, weeks))";
}
return $weeks;
```

Please help me how can I run this code?

Comment: It's supposed to do that, the format string should be quoted in the `date` function

Comment: and `Mon` should be `"Mon"` (`Mon`  is probably an undefined constant).

Comment: and `week = 1;` should be `$week = 1;` - You might benefit from going through some basic PHP 101 tutorials to learn the fundamentals.

Comment: You may only have noticed the change if you recently updated to 8.0+ because an undefined constant now falls under `Throwable` type instead of emitting a standard warning in previous versions which would still fail gracefully. Just worth noting, but otherwise I agree. You should always quote a string.